# terminology for the opposite of annotated?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I have a dataset which is annotated, used both for training and testing.
And I have another dataset which is not annotated, used for production.

Currently I call them `AnnotatedDataset` and `UnannotatedDataset`. I am looking for a better term for `UnannotatedDataset` (simply calling it `Dataset` is not the answer that I am looking for, because I want to be explicit here).

**Update**

Example of annotated data:

```
<citation><author>Murre , J. </author><title>An analysis of implementation constraints and performance . </title><journal>IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks</journal></citation>
```

Example of unannotated data:

```
Murre , J. An analysis of implementation constraints and performance . IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks
```

Comment: If by annotated you mean the metadata that is attached to describe your data that I don't see why the use of unannotated where the data has no metadata is problematic

Comment: What does annotated dataset mean in the first place? It could mean different things given different types of data.

Comment: i've updated the question with an example of annotated data

Comment: This looks more like formatted and unformatted textual data.

Comment: thx @Carl. I ended up calling it Raw and Tagged.

Answer (score 2):

Extensible Markup Language ([XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XM)) is the general description of the set of rules for encoding documents in a format that is both human-readable and machine-readable of the root type used in OP's first example. As of 2009, 100 document formats using XML syntax had been developed.

The second OP example is plain text without XML encoding.

One alternative would be to call the two streams `XML` and `text`, although frankly, the alternatives are too numerous to strongly suggest any particular choice of terms.

Comment: the names "xml" and "text" do not convey the idea that one is used for training and the other not. I ended up calling them Tagged and Raw.

Comment: I worried about what they are, and not what their intended usage is. As I said, there are too many alternatives to strongly suggest any particular labels. "Tagged" while as good as any other label, does not suggest truth data for training as well as "decoded, encoded, truth, train, IDed", and dozens of others.